# WordPress menu is placed outside the header

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-menu-item

If the user goes to a page other than the homepage then my header changes layout.

Everything works fine except for the function `wp_nav_menu`.

First, I check whether the user is on the homepage or not. Depending on that outcome the user is shown one of two headers.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
    $menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'hoofdmenu' ) );
    echo is_front_page() ? '' : '
    <header>
        <div class="hoofdmenu">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <a href="#" id="click-a"><img width="80" height="80" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/hamburger.png"></a>
            </div>
            '.$menu.'
        </div>
    </header>';
?>
```

To keep it short I deleted the `true` value of the `if` statement.

Now the problem that I have is that the menu is placed completely outside the `header`

Here is the HTML output:

```
<div class="menu-hoofdmenu-container">
    <ul id="menu-hoofdmenu" class="menu">
        <li>Menu item 1</li>
        <li>Menu item 2</li>
        <li>Menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>      
    <header>
        <div class="hoofdmenu">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <a href="#" id="click-a"><img width="80" height="80" src="http://www.url.nl/wp-content/themes/themename/images/hamburger.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Any thoughts on why the `wp_nav_menu` is placed outside the `header`?

-------Update--------

```
echo is_front_page() ? '' : '

    <header>
        <div class="hoofdmenu">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <a href="#" id="click-a"><img width="80" height="80" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/hamburger.png"></a>
            </div>
            '.wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'hoofdmenu' ) ).'
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Added an update at the bottom of the answer, you can skip the first part)*

According to the [Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), the function displays (`echo`) the menu and **doesn't return it**.

> wp_nav_menu( array $args = array() )
>
> Displays a navigation menu.

Therefore, when you use

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'hoofdmenu' ) );
```

You actually print the menu rather than saving it in the `$menu` variable and therefore it's being printed prior to the header's code.

The solution would be:

```
echo is_front_page() ? '' : '
<header>
    <div class="hoofdmenu">
        <div class="hamburger">
            <a href="#" id="click-a"><img width="80" height="80" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/hamburger.png"></a>
        </div>
        '.wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'hoofdmenu' ) ).'
    </div>
</header>';
```

**UPDATE:**

Try the following:

```
if(!is_front_page()){

    echo '<header>
        <div class="hoofdmenu">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <a href="#" id="click-a"><img width="80" height="80" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/hamburger.png"></a>
            </div>';

            wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'hoofdmenu' ) );

    echo '
        </div>
    </header>';
}
```

**Better update:**

Use the same code you were using, just add the 'echo' option to the args array.
It seems that you can tell the function to return the output instead of printing it.

> 'echo' (bool) Whether to echo the menu or return it. Default true.

Usage:

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'hoofdmenu', 'echo' => false) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution. Give echo false and your code will work.
From WP Docs.

```
//'echo'
//(bool) Whether to echo the menu or return it. Default true.

$menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'hoofdmenu', 'echo' => false ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I could solve it by setting the echo to false.

`wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'yourtheme', 'echo' => false ) );`